# Rewrite Rule to Create Directory Shortcut

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file that is located at:

http://www.mydomain.com/alcamino/includes/display_objects/custom/camino-tools/RemotingService.cfc

I would like to be able to access RemotingService.cfc like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/remoting/RemotingService.cfc

I have tried several different Rewrite rules but none are working correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Any other ideas???? This didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in your document good

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?remoting/RemotingService.cfc$ /alcamino/includes/display_objects/custom/camino-tools/RemotingService.cfc [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I get an object moved message. Any other ideas?